# View menu bar & bookmarks toolbar in Firefox 4 full-screen mode?

Tags: firefox-extensions, firefox

In Firefox 3.6, I was using the [Autohide extension](http://www.krickelkrackel.de/autohide/) to enable the menu bar and bookmarks toolbar in full screen mode.  But Autohide is not compatible with Firefox 4, and even its home page appears to be gone. (Here's an [old copy on the Wayback Machine](http://replay.web.archive.org/20070702230344/http://www.krickelkrackel.de/autohide/).)

In Firefox 4's full-screen mode, when I move the mouse to the top of the screen, only the navigation toolbar and the tab list appear.  I want to see the menu bar and bookmarks toolbar as well.  I also want to be able to use `Alt` keys to open the menu (e.g. `Alt-V` to open the View menu.)

Is there an extension compatible with Firefox 4 that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a month without any answers here, I posted this question to the [Firefox Help forum](https://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions) and got a solution in half an hour.

[cor-el wrote](https://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/825114#answer-187641):

Add code to userChrome.css below the `@namespace` line.

- http://kb.mozillazine.org/userChrome.css
- http://kb.mozillazine.org/Editing_configuration

You can use the [ChromEdit Plus](http://webdesigns.ms11.net/chromeditp.html) extension to have easier access to the customization files.

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"); /* only needed once */

#toolbar-menubar[moz-collapsed="true"] { visibility: visible !important; }
#PersonalToolbar[moz-collapsed="true"] { visibility: visible !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late in the game, but... have you tried Add-on Compatibility Reporter https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-on-compatibility-reporter/?src=api and Nightly Testers Tool to override compatibility issues?

I'm running Firefox 5 with this and the dozen addons i have work just fine.

Comment: I guess I'll have to try that, but as I mentioned, the Autohide extension is no longer available, so even if it works with 4.0.1, eventually something will break it.  So, I'm still looking for a supported solution.

Answer (score 0):

For those who don't want to mess with their chrome file directly, as described in cjm's accepted answer, you can use that code in a style file and use it with [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/?src=external-userstyleshome) as follows:

Create a blank style, paste that text into it, and save it.

EDIT: create a blank style by clicking on stylish icon in toolbar and selecting 'write a new style' and then selecting 'blank style'

Comment: Can you expand your answer to explain how to create a blank style?

Comment: @fixer1234 Ouch.  You changed "chrome" to "Chrome".  I believe rezad was referring to Firefox's chrome, not Google Chrome.  That capitalization causes confusion, not clarity.  The "chrome" in Mozilla Firefox refers to the stuff outside the main viewing area (where the HTML content goes), and the term is older than the Google Chrome web browser, so it's not Mozilla's fault that the term got doubled up.

Comment: @TOOGAM: I learned something new.  Thanks.  Fixed it.